# Shell scipt to convert bit string to text value code

Tags: linux, bash, sh, ksh

I have 32 bit string of 0s. Each bit in the string represents some code, for e.g.

```
1000000000000000000000000000000  = ABC
0100000000000000000000000000000 = DEF
...
0000000000000000000000000000001 = XYZ
```

I have file of string bit, is there any way to shell script the output to code 
for. e.g

```
1100000000000000000000000000000  should print ABC|DEF
```

Thanks for your inputs.

edit1:
@nullPointer : the 3 digit letters are example of human readable representation of the 32 bit representation.

Comment: [Simillar question from neighboring board](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/98948/ascii-to-binary-and-binary-to-ascii-conversion-tools)

Comment: @Denis Sheremet , thanks but I do not want ot convert ASCII to binary but text to text based on some value.

Comment: You can parse bit numbers with arithmetic expansion with specifying the base. Ex. `echo $((2#1010))` outputs 10. Take the numbers, extract each bit separately with a mask and translate to the strings.

Comment: @ForeverLearner : Yes, you can do it, but bash would not be the best-suited programming language for with task. Why don't you do it in a language you are familiar with? And what is actually your concrete question?

Comment: @ user1934428 , because it is a quick task. These tasks are needed for quick work.Gordon Davisson's answer has exactly tackled my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In bash:

```
codes=("ABC" "DEF" ... "XYZ")
bitstring=1100000000000000000000000000000

outstring=""
for i in {0..31}; do
    if [ "${bitstring:i:1}" = 1 ]; then
        outstring+="|${codes[i]}"
    fi
done
echo "${outstring#|}"
```

Comment: Wow, Gordon Davisson. Thanks a lot , this is exactly what I was looking for. Sincere thanks :)